# Can I safely remove the Via http header?

Tags: http, reverse-proxy

I have a Internet facing service that provides APIs over https - json, xml and the like - something like https://api.example.org/api/foo. The API's are generally built from corporate internal services, but even if we are making requests to external internet based service I want them to appear to clients as my services.

From a User-Agent perspective https://api.example.org is the Origin server.

We have bought a fancy vendor API gateway product to secure the APIs. So far so good.

Currently the gateway is appending a Via header to the requests which contain the internal hostname of the server that processes the request, which is not so good.

```
 > GET /api/foo/bar HTTP/1.1
 > User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
 > Host: api.example.org
 > Accept: */*
 > 
 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 < Content-Type: application/json
 < Date: Thu, 15 Mar 2015 22:11:46 GMT
 < Max-Forwards: 20
 * Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
 < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 < Via: 1.0 myinternalhostname.local (Apache-Coyote/1.1)
 < transfer-encoding: chunked
 < Connection: keep-alive
```

Whether they can use it or not, I dont want the bots and bad guys knowing my hostnames.

Can I remove the Via header, or should I sanitise it to the public name, eg

```
< Via: 1.0 api.example.org (Apache-Coyote/1.1)
```

I know why the Via header exists and I don't think my api server needs meet the RFC since its acting as an Origin server. (even though in reality it's a gateway/reverse proxy, the client doesn't need to know this).

TL;DR

Is it safe to remove the Via header from an Origin server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Via header is designed for passing the blame on to someone else.

It is perfectly acceptable to remove, or not generate it, if it doesn't serve that purpose.